# How can I efficiently assign the same option values to multiple Select elements in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, spacebars

I have multiple Select elements that need to contain the same values. Rather than duplicate the same HTML in every Select of this type:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
```

...I want to either use a Template helper to supply those values, such as something like:

HTML:

```
<select class="jobLocCount" id="date1Shift1JobLoc2Count" name="date1Shift1JobLoc2Count">
   {{> jobLocCountVals}}
</select>
```

JS:

```
Template.tblScheduler.helpers({
  jobLocCountVals: function() {
  return '<option value="1">1</option>'+
  '<option value="2">2</option>'+
  '<option value="3">3</option>'+
  '<option value="4">4</option>'+
  '<option value="5">5</option>'+
  '<option value="6">6</option>'+
  '<option value="7">7</option>'+
  '<option value="8">8</option>'+
  '<option value="9">9</option>'+
  '<option value="10">10</option>'
  }
});
```

...OR assign the option values directly in HTML to the first Select of this type, and then assign all the rest via js, something like (pseudocode):

```
Template.tblScheduler.onRender({
    $('#date1Shift1JobLoc2Count').Items = $('#date1Shift1JobLoc1Count').Items;
    $('#date1Shift1JobLoc3Count').Items = $('#date1Shift1JobLoc1Count').Items;
    . . .
});
```

My question is, which approach is better, and how exactly would the better approach be realized (the above is just rather far-fetched pseudocode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go about it this way, why not return an array of objects (effectively how a Meteor cursor works) in a template helper, and iterate over them? You can hardcode the objects, but you can also create a loop in the JS to do that for you if you like.

Here's a hardcoded example since it appears you need option values ranging from 1-10:

**JavaScript Template Helper**

```
  Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    values: function () {
     return [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}, {value: 4}, {value: 5}, {value: 6},    
      {value: 7}, {value: 8}, {value: 9}, {value: 10}];
    }
  });
```

**HTML Template**

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
  <select id="whateverYouWant" class="whateverYouWant">
      {{#each values}}
        <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
      {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

I chose to go this route because it's essentially what Meteor is doing when you return the results of a Mongo query, except with hardcoded values, and makes use of Meteor's `{{#each}}` spacebars syntax.

As an added bonus, if you wanted to make this a global template helper, available to any template, you can do this:

```
Template.registerHelper("selectValues", function() {
         return [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}, {value: 4}, {value: 5}, {value: 6},    
          {value: 7}, {value: 8}, {value: 9}, {value: 10}];
});
```